# hi, i'm new to Python and im trying to learn Data analysis using python and im having trouble with this code

Tags: python

This code is not showing the correct mean values.

```
from pandas import*
import numpy
m={'ground forces':Series(['30','45','51','66','38'],index=['a','b','c','d','e']),'naval forces':Series(['76','100','91','178','81'],index=['a','b','c','d','e']),'air forces':Series(['212','28','92','77','55'],index=['a','b','c','d','e'])}
k=DataFrame(m)
print(k)
print(k.apply(numpy.mean))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: I didn't get any errors but the output mean values are all wrong.               this is the output i got:                                                                           air forces       4.245786e+09
ground forces    6.091033e+08
naval forces     1.522018e+11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that your problem was that you are using strings instead of numbers in the definition of your series:
Here is the correct code:

```
from pandas import*
import numpy

m = {
    'ground forces' : Series([30,45,51,66,38], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']),
    'naval forces' : Series([76,100,91,178,81], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']),
    'air forces' : Series([212, 28, 92, 77, 55], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
}

k=DataFrame(m)
print(k)
print(k.apply(numpy.mean))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,really appreciate it. it works.